# Eliminar un numero de filas determinado justo después de detectar un valor en una celda específica con Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo el siguiente dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [23,4,13,15,'out','out2',41,25,25,'out3','out4',53,23,48,49,54,55,'out5','out6',16],
                   'B': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'señal',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'señal',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'señal',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                   'C': [0,0,0,1,3,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6],
                   'D': [1,4,3,1,3,3,1,2,5,2,3,5,3,4,9,4,5,8,6,6]})
```

Intento que por cada fila de la columna B en la que se encuentra el valor 'señal' se borren las 2 filas de abajo.

Para hacerlo estoy intentandolo de este modo:

```
señales=[] #Creo un array para poner los numeros de index de filas que contienen 'señal'
for i in range (len(df)):  
    s_indexes = df[df.B == 'señal'].index[i]  # Extraigo los index que contienen 'señal' y luego los añado al array mediante append
    señales.append(s_indexes) 

for i in range (len(df)): #Ahora hago otro loop en el que pretendo eliminar las 2 filas posteriores a la fila que contiene señal 
    df2 = df.drop([int(señales[i+2])], axis=0, inplace = True)
```

Sin embargo no lo consigo.
El resultado debería ser un dataframe como este pero sin las filas 4,5,9,10,17,18:

```
       A      B  C  D
0     23    NaN  0  1
1      4    NaN  0  4
2     13    NaN  0  3
3     15  señal  1  1
4    out    NaN  3  3
5   out2    NaN  1  3
6     41    NaN  1  1
7     25    NaN  2  2
8     25  señal  2  5
9   out3    NaN  2  2
10  out4    NaN  3  3
11    53    NaN  3  5
12    23    NaN  3  3
13    48    NaN  4  4
14    49    NaN  4  9
15    54    NaN  5  4
16    55  señal  5  5
17  out5    NaN  5  8
18  out6    NaN  6  6
19    16    NaN  6  6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre la siguiente solución. No me convence mucho el uso de variables globales. Podrían evitarse usando una clase en lugar de la función, pero complica innecesariamente el código. Al final muestro esa variante.

La idea es tener una función que reciba una fila del dataframe y returne `True` si la línea debe conservarse y `False` si no. Usaremos esa función en un `.apply()` para seleccionar solo las filas que retornen `True`.

La función mantiene un contador global y mientras ese contador sea negativo retornará `True` (la fila se mantiene) y si es positivo retornará `False` (hay que borrarla). El truco por tanto es poner el contador a 2 cada vez que se detecta "señal", y decrementarlo en cada llamada a la función.

Esta sería esa función:

```
contador_a_borrar = 0

def elegir_filas(fila):
  global contador_a_borrar
  contador_a_borrar -= 1
  ok = (contador_a_borrar <0) # No borrar mientras sea negativo
  if fila["B"] == "señal":
    contador_a_borrar = 2     # Borrará las dos siguientes
  return ok
```

Y esta sería la forma de usarla:

```
df2 = df[df.apply(elegir_filas, axis=1)]
```

Con tu ejemplo el resultado que sale es:

```
     A      B  C  D
0   23    NaN  0  1
1    4    NaN  0  4
2   13    NaN  0  3
3   15  señal  1  1
6   41    NaN  1  1
7   25    NaN  2  2
8   25  señal  2  5
11  53    NaN  3  5
12  23    NaN  3  3
13  48    NaN  4  4
14  49    NaN  4  9
15  54    NaN  5  4
16  55  señal  5  5
19  16    NaN  6  6
```

### Versión sin variables globales

El truco aquí es usar una clase que guarde en un atributo de objeto ese contador. La clase debe implementar el método `__call__()` para poder ser utilizada como una función:

```
class ElegirFilas:
  def __init__(self):
    self.contador_a_borrar = 0

  def __call__(self, fila):
    self.contador_a_borrar -= 1
    ok = (self.contador_a_borrar <0) # No borrar mientras sea negativo
    if fila["B"] == "señal":
      self.contador_a_borrar = 2     # Borrará las dos siguientes
    return ok

df2 = df[df.apply(ElegirFilas(), axis=1)]
```

Observa que ahora a `apply()` se le pasa `ElegirFilas()`, que es un objeto instancia de la clase vista más arriba, y no la clase en sí, pues `.apply()` intentará "llamar" a lo que se pase como primer parámetro. Si fuera una clase, esa "llamada" simplemente instanciaría un objeto en vez de ejecutar `__call__()`. Al pasarle un objeto, el intento de "llamar" al objeto como si fuera una función causa que se ejecute su método `__call__()` que en este caso es lo que queremos.

Ya avisé de que esto complicaría el código :-) La ventaja sobre la primera solución es que en la primera, si queremos usar varias veces el truco para filtrar diferentes dataframes, hay que recordar volver a poner a 0 la variable global entre filtrado y filtrado. En la segunda no hay este problema porque `__init__()` se ocupa de volver a poner a cero el atributo cada vez que se instancia un nuevo objeto de la clase.

Comment: Ambos ejemplos son geniales. Es cierto que el segundo ejemplo es un poco más complejo, pero dependiendo de los objetivos, puede ser mejor. En mi caso el primer ejemplo ya me va muy bien, puesto que no empleo un script demasiado complejo, así que la variable global no me causa complicaciones. Muchas gracias por la explicación.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

**Nota:** Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable **no** utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el `dataset` rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un `for` entonces es el camino incorrecto (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces `apply` podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos.

Hay otra forma de hacerlo utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) y así evitar el `apply`.

Primero hay que encontrar las filas donde `df['B'] == 'señal'` y obtener el índice, para eso se pueden utilizar `slices`, `loc` o `iloc`. Por simplicidad voy a utilizar `slices`:

```
df[df['B'] == 'señal'].index
```

Teniendo el índice de las filas donde `df['B'] == 'señal'` es muy fácil encontrar las siguientes dos filas, solo hay que sumarle 1 y 2 respectivamente.

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [23,4,13,15,'out','out2',41,25,25,'out3','out4',53,23,48,49,54,55,'out5','out6',16],
                   'B': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'señal',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'señal',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'señal',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                   'C': [0,0,0,1,3,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6],
                   'D': [1,4,3,1,3,3,1,2,5,2,3,5,3,4,9,4,5,8,6,6]})

# Eliminar la fila con el índice + 1 al encontrar "señal"
df.drop(df[df['B'] == 'señal'].index + 1, inplace = True)

# Eliminar la fila con el índice + 2 al encontrar "señal"
df.drop(df[df['B'] == 'señal'].index + 2, inplace = True)

# Restablecer el índice (En caso de que lo utilices puedes quitar el #)
#df.reset_index(inplace = True)

print(df)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
     A      B  C  D
0   23    NaN  0  1
1    4    NaN  0  4
2   13    NaN  0  3
3   15  señal  1  1
6   41    NaN  1  1
7   25    NaN  2  2
8   25  señal  2  5
11  53    NaN  3  5
12  23    NaN  3  3
13  48    NaN  4  4
14  49    NaN  4  9
15  54    NaN  5  4
16  55  señal  5  5
19  16    NaN  6  6
```

**Nota:** Tal como está el código mostrado una desventaja es que si `señal` se encuentra en la última o penúltima fila entonces devolverá un error diciendo:

```
KeyError: '[20] not found in axis'
```

Donde `20` será el índice que no es posible encontrar ya que no existen más filas

Si estás seguro que siempre va a haber por lo menos 2 filas después de `señal` entonces tal como está el código te va a funcionar, en caso contrario puedes agregar el argumento `errors = 'ignore'` de esta forma:

```
# Eliminar la fila con el índice + 1 al encontrar "señal"
df.drop(df[df['B'] == 'señal'].index + 1, inplace = True, errors = 'ignore')

# Eliminar la fila con el índice + 2 al encontrar "señal"
df.drop(df[df['B'] == 'señal'].index + 2, inplace = True, errors = 'ignore')
```

Y así no va a devolver error aunque no haya filas después de `señal`.